# Control threads with Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, multitasking

In some code like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) //each iteration in another task
{
     Method2();

}
//Task.WaitAll()

public void Method2()
{
    Method3();
}

public void Method3()
{
    Method4();
}

public void Method4()
{
    process1.Start(); //this process take a lot of time so next iteration/next task should start in this place
}
```

I'd like run each iteration in other thread, but not all at one. One thread should go to Method4(), run it, and wait to ending this process. Later another thread with the same behavior etc. And in Task.WaitAll() program should wait for all threads.

How to do this? 2 Tasks in one iteration, ContinueWith or sth?

Comment: You left out Method1, and Method2 is there twice. Also indicate if/where there is any CPU intensive processing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother.

All iterations quickly end up executing Method4() and you want that single threaded.

Under that constraint this is not a scenario for Tasks or Threads at all.

---

But assuming there is something substantial happening in Method2() and/or Method3(), you could replace the `for()` loop with `Parallel.For()` and use a simple `lock` around the Process code:

```
private static object processLock = new object();  // probably static

public void Method4()
{
   lock(processLock)
   {
       process1.Start(); 
   }
}
```

But now you have to guard against the TPL creating too many Threads. (use DegreeOfParallelism in Parallel.For).

Comment: No, process1 takes almost 1 hour so I want run it several times to make better use of processor

Comment: Then maybe explain the "not all at once" part a little better?  And remove MethodX when they have no function here.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want to run all these processes in paraller, but you want to limit how many processes will run concurrently right? For that you can use semaphores, which limit concurrency (but be aware that all threads will be all pending whole time - so mark them as LongRunning).

another thing is that you must wait in Method4 for process to exit.

```
static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim (3); // Capacity of 3

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) //each iteration in another task
{
     tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
         Method2();
     }, 
     TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks)

public void Method2()
{
    Method3();
}

public void Method3()
{
    Method4();
}

public void Method4()
{
    semaphore.Wait();
    process1.Start(); 
    process1.WaitForExit();
    semaphore.Release();
}
```